# Nmap - Print names from virtual hosts

Tags: virtualhost, nmap

I'm trying to identify virtual hosts with Nmap, command:

```
nmap --script http-vhosts -p80 {ip}
```

Nmap identifies a number of hosts. But how do I get the actual host names that are found? Now nmap only prints "128 names had status 200".

[image: Screenshot - output]

Comment: nmap -v --script http-vhosts -p80 {ip}

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for [Script http-vhosts](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-vhosts.html):

> **Script Arguments**
>
> `http-vhosts.collapse`
>
> The limit to start collapsing results by status code. Default 20

As the 128 names is more than the default 20, the results will be collapsed; you need to set this argument to be over 128.

How to use the NSE scripts arguments?

Read the *The Official Nmap Project Guide to Network Discovery and Security Scanning*; [Nmap Network Scanning](https://nmap.org/book/toc.html) > [Chapter 9. Nmap Scripting Engine](https://nmap.org/book/nse.html) > [Usage and Examples](https://nmap.org/book/nse-usage.html) > [Arguments to Scripts](https://nmap.org/book/nse-usage.html#nse-args):

> Arguments may be passed to NSE scripts using the `--script-args` option. The arguments describe a table of key-value pairs and possibly array values. - -
>
> The syntax for script arguments is similar to Lua's table constructor syntax. Arguments are a comma-separated list of name=value pairs. Names and values may be strings not containing whitespace or the characters `{`, `}`, `=`, or `,`. To include one of these characters in a string, enclose the string in single or double quotes. Within a quoted string, `\` escapes a quote. A backslash is only used to escape quotation marks in this special case; in all other cases a backslash is interpreted literally.

```
nmap --script http-vhosts --script-args http-vhosts.collapse=200 -p80 {ip}
```